# Google pay transaction fails with 409 error

Tags: android, google-pay

We integrated Google pay with tokenization type as TOKENIZATION_DIRECT with public_key added as a parameter.

> .setPaymentMethodTokenizationType(
>                                  WalletConstants.PAYMENT_METHOD_TOKENIZATION_TYPE_DIRECT)
>   .addParameter("publicKey", "...key..")

But, the transaction fails with error code 409, which means as per documentation

> Not immediately recoverable error. There are problems with the buyer's
>   account (e.g closed account, unsupported country)

We verified reasons closed and unsupported country, both are okay.
What other reasons could it be?

Comment: Can you try the steps outlined in the troubleshooting section and update your post: https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/support/troubleshooting

Comment: did you manage to find a answer, I am having the same issue

Comment: Having the _exact_ same problem - this Google Pay is turning out to be a pain in the behind :(

Answer (score 0):

### Google Pay Error Codes:

- **400**  Request contains an invalid argument.
- **504**  Deadline expired before operation could complete.
- **404**  Requested entity was not found. List item
- **409**  Request entity already exists.
- **403**  The caller does not have permission.
- **429**  Resource has been exhausted (eg.check quote).
- **400** Precondition check failed.
- **409**  The operation was aborted.
- **500**  Internal error encountered.
- **503**  The service is unavailable.
- **401**  The request does not have valid authenticated credentials.

Comment: Where is this from? I can't find this documentation anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wallet/WalletConstants#public-static-final-int-error_code_buyer_account_error
According to that 409 stands for

```
public static final int ERROR_CODE_BUYER_ACCOUNT_ERROR
```

> Not immediately recoverable error. There are problems with the buyer's account (e.g closed account, unsupported country)